# Rails 3 set default actions for response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application i need to set some deafult actions for all `format.js` and `format.htm` responses. At this moment I have something like this in all controllers:

```
def index
  @users = User.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {html_response}
    format.js {js_response}
  end
end
```

But I think that it isn't a good solution. What can I do?

Comment: And how does `html_response` and `js_response` look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a private method in your `ApplicationController` and call it from wherever required

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  …
  private

  def default_responses
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {html_response}
      format.js   {js_response}
    end
  end
end


class SomethingsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @somethings = Something.all
    default_responses
  end
end
```